# Move full wordpress install from a domain into another domain's sub folder

Tags: database, wordpress, phpmyadmin, migration

- In the same host I have 2 domains: oldstuff.com and maindomain.com
- both have wordpress installed and obviously a respective database
- I want to delete oldstuff.com and transfer all the content to maindomain.com/oldstuff
- via FTP I create the folder oldstuff inside the directory of maindomain.com
- via FTP I transfer the entire contents of the maindomain.com folder and transfer it inside maindomain.com/oldstuff
- now only the database part is missing:
- I go into the oldstuff.com database via phpmyadmin and do:
- command 1: UPDATE wp_options SET option_value = replace(option_value, 'oldstuff.com', 'maindomain.com/oldstuff') WHERE option_name = 'home' OR option_name = 'maindomain.com/oldstuff';
- command 2: UPDATE wp_postmeta SET meta_value = replace(meta_value, 'oldstuff.com', 'maindomain.com/oldstuff');
- command 3: UPDATE wp_posts SET post_content = REPLACE(post_content, 'oldstuff.com', 'maindomain.com/oldstuff');

Done everything. But it doesn't work. Did I forget some steps?

Already
Described
What I tried

Comment: Use a migration plugin like Duplicator. Make a "package" from oldstuff. Then install it, following the plugin's directions, in the subdirectory.

Comment: @O.Jones too late, I have already moved the whole content via FTP and database like explained. The weirdest part is the main page is open regularly, but when I click on the posts within it, it will open maindomain.com/oldstuff/anyposts.php/%3Ca%20href= and keeps refreshing forever. Any idea what's wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

Solved. Just need to go to permalinks page, to do nothing, press save. And it magically works. LOL. Weird issue.